# Circular images

Tags: vb.net, image, picturebox, shapes

In my application, users are allowed to choose a picture they want and this picture shows up in a picturebox. 
I want to know if there was a way so that this picture that they select becomes circular instead of a square?
I want all images they select to be circle shaped.

Is there anyway to do this? Doesn't even have to be a picturebox control, anything that can accomplish this is fine

I tried this with no luck - http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/430531/circle-shaped-picture-box

Comment: You can put a circular image in a picturebox

Answer (score 0):

Not the smartest way, but worked for me in similar task. If your picturebox is fixed size, you can create "mask" which will hide the corners.

Just draw an image in PNG with transparent circle in the middle and make the rest same color as your form. Use this image as Image propperty of each imagebox and set your image as "backgroundImage" property. This way, the image will look circle-shaped.

If you need imageboxes of different size, you can create the circle mask programmatically.

EDIT: If you will prepare a calculation of circle, you can also use it to "crop" the images to circle shape. It all depends on what you want to do with these images later.
Do you need to use them later in circle or rectangle shape?